# Moving EditETxt Cursor to the end of spannable text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor-position

I have Edittext where i set spannable text into it and i want the cursor at the end of spannable text . so that user can input manuuly from key board.

i have already tried

```
ObjectOfEdietext.setSelection(ObjectOfEdietext.getText().lenght());
```

but it is not working for me. but if i set normal text on the Editext and do the same, it works well.
Can anyone point out whats the problem??

thanks in advance

**Edited**
Here i found the problem that LinkMovementMethod which i have set on edit text for making span text clickable, is disabling edittext cursor. Another big problem after i faced is when i set  clickable spanned text on edittext then cursor move to 0 postion so i am unable to move cursor at the end of text to add text from keyboard ! has anyone faced such problem before?

Comment: try to convert it into a string. getText().toString().length();

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
ObjectOfEdietext.setSelection(ObjectOfEdietext.getText().toString().lenght());
```

i have personally tried with following code and its working

```
et_from.setText(new SpannableString("my starting Address"));
et_from.setSelection(et_from.getText().length());
```

Comment: thanks @dinesh for quick respone. but it was due the setting MovementMethod in edittext for eg.
phoneNum.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); i set it for making span clickable, and the purpose is to delete spannedString.

Comment: i want to move the cursor to the end of string and also wan delete touch spanned String. problem is that it a complementary to each other. if i set the movementMethod i am unable to move the cursor at the end and if i didnt i am unable to make span clickable

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it is working 100%:

```
yourEditText.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        yourEditText.setSelection(yourBubbleText.length());
     }
});
```